# Como alimentar notificações em tempo real enquanto usuário logado?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

estou querendo um sistema que fica atualizando o usuário logado pra ir mostrando as mensagens que ele recebe. Levando em consideração que esse sistema vai ter aí 250-500 usuários simultâneos, qual a melhor forma de buscar os dados no banco de dados e ir atualizando a caixa de mensagens do usuário? Eu pensei em rodar um script a cada minuto e atualizar todo mundo logado mas não sei se este é o melhor caminho. Pretendo fazer isso via Ajax com setInterval mas estou aberto a ideias visto que nunca fiz e não sei qual a melhor implementação.

O que me preocupa é sobrecarga do servidor!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Long Poling ou WebSocket ou Ajax.

Comment: @Gumball pode me explicar um pouco sobre o funcionamento dessas tecnologias?

Answer (score 2):

Se tratando em uma aplicação desenvolvida para web, não há um caminho para onde fugir. As únicas maneiras de criar atualizações para o cliente são:

Criar regras de negocio no computador do proprio cliente (Solução para caso o cliente vá realizar uma atividade em sua propria maquina, como ser alertado após preencher um formulario corretamente ou realizar um parse de um arquivo via js).

Bater no servidor via ajax, solicitando e tratando os dados recebidos. (Creio que esta deverá ser sua abordagem)

Ok, mas e sobre "pesar no servidor"?

A proposta do ajax é miniminizar a quantidade de dados trafegados, de forma a realizar pequenas solicitações ao servidor e aproveitar os dados já fornecidos. Então a solução seria criar um endpoint para buscar somente os dados necessários. Exemplo:

Computador do cliente realiza a requisição:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/checkUpdates",
    data: {
        userId: 1,
        lastMessageId: 1
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        verifyAjaxReponse(response);
    }
});
```

Você coleta os dados enviados pelo usúario, e os compara com o recebido:

```
$data = json_decode($params); //dados vindos pelo ajax
$result = $db->exec('select lastMessageId where userId = "' . $data['userId'] . '"');

if ($data['lastMessageId'] == $result['lastMessageId']) { //Supondo que a request não passe por aqui, e exista um novo resultado
    $result == false;
}
$framework->disableLayout();
$framework->view = json_encode($result); // $result = ['message' => 'Você recebeu uma nova mensagem. Verifique sua caixa de entrada', 'id'];
```

Depois disso, os dados serão minificados e retornados para a maquina do cliente, onde seu javascript poderá verificar se a response possui alguma atualização e gerar o alerta.

```
success: function(response) {
    verifyAjaxReponse(response);
}
```